# Arcpy Python Snippet for SQL "LIKE" expression problem

Tags: arcpy, sql, where-clause

I am trying to use `arcpy.Select_analysis` in python code with ArcGIS for straightforward geoprocessing. I have a field called "other tags" in a vector dataset which I want to select any record which contains the word "rail".

I can get it working interactively by typing the following code into the query builder:

```
"other_tags"LIKE ('%rail%')
```

When I copy it as a python snippet it gives me:

```
arcpy.Select_analysis(in_features=input, out_feature_class=output, where_clause='"other_tags"LIKE ('%rail%')\n')
```

and when I try and run this code directly rather than through the interface it doesn't work. The error is:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting.
```

I am not clear how to amend the where_clause to make it work.

Comment: Try making your WHERE clause into a string variable first, then using that variable in the Select_analysis function.

Comment: thanks Dan - I tried that but the %rail% doesn't seem to transfer properly - could you share how you would write the string variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quotes inside the query must be escaped:

```
arcpy.Select_analysis(in_features=input, out_feature_class=output, where_clause='"other_tags" LIKE (\'%rail%\')')
```

Comment: Thanks JGH - that worked!

Comment: Also you would not end your where clause with a newline character. I see that JGH has removed that too.